# embed feed from yammer using access token

Tags: embed, yammer

How to Embed Feed from yammer using access token skipping the yammer login?
I have access token for yammer login. I need to get the yammer feed using the access token.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:800px;width:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: "#embedded-feed",
  network: "{rede}",
  feedType: "{type}",
  feedId: "{id}"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its working, But I have to login to yammer in- order to get this feed. Is there any way to get the feed using the yammer access token.

Comment: to get the access token you need to authenticate once with an verified admin, after that this token never expired.

Comment: I got that access token. How can i embed yammer feed using the access token 
 yam.connect.embedFeed(
          { container: '#embedded-feed',
            network: 'example.com' 
        });

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use angularJS or pure JS to send the pre-obtained token as a bearer token in the authorization header. Something like:

```
function YammerGetMsgCtrl($scope, $http ) {  
 $http.get('https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN_VALUE'}}).  
      success(function(data) {  
       $scope.messages = data;  
      console.log($scope.messages)  
     });  
 }
```

See this blog post for details - http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2015/02/24/consuming-yammer-restful-api-with-angularjs-for-dummies.aspx

Comment: How can i embed yammer feed using the access token 
 yam.connect.embedFeed(
          { container: '#embedded-feed',
            network: 'example.com' 
        });

Comment: You can't add any customisation to the out-of-the-box embed feed. Users will always need to re-login if their session expires. The above solution however, can be used to build your own custom ui if (and only if) embed doesn't suit your requirement.